# Ph.d thesis assessment

Tags: dg.differential-geometry

Hi!
I would like to put my thesis (in Poisson geometry) online for an assessment, so I can receive feedback to improve the manuscript. Can you help me to find the right place to my request?
Thank you.

Another related question, may one attach some pdf files to questions here?

Comment: I'm not sure how many random strangers you'll get to read your thesis that way. I'd think that this is what all those conferences where you made friends with the fellow students and researchers in your field were for.

Comment: My feeling is that this is what supervisors and fellow students are for, rather than random strangers. As such I don't think this request is appropriate for MO

Comment: Did this really need to be closed? It's two specific questions, both of which have answers that might be helpful to graduate students. @Amine: Here are the answers to your questions. (1) People have posted their theses on the ArXiv (www.arxiv.org). In the note accompanying one's post, one can request comments. Whether one receives any comments is another issue, but there's no harm in posting. (2) It would not be appropriate to attach a thesis or an article PDF to a MathOverflow posting.

Comment: Dear Amine, I suggest first to post the thesis on your homepage. After doing so you can certainly include the link to your thesis on your homepage (or on the arxive) in the body of your question. You can also email a small number of experts about your results and also include such a link. (Overall, the level of polishing I would recommend for an arxive posting is higher than what I would require for posting on a personal homepage).  Good luck!

Comment: I was afraid to be baned after my questions :)
Many thanks for your kind and useful responses!
I am posting the manuscript on arxiv.org, all what i need is 'endorsement'.
Thanks once again.

Comment: I agree with @Joe Silverman's entire comment above. The question should not have been closed, and I have voted that it be reopened so that Joe Silverman can post the comment above as an answer. @amine: your adviser probably does not know how to give you an endorsement, but probably is technically able to, if you sit down at the computer with them. Certain academic IP adresses/emails do not require endorsements to post to arXiv. Please do not post a link to your thesis here. Presumably, by now _you_ are the expert on your thesis topic, and we should ask you questions about the results therein.

Answer (score 2):

Hello,

With the help of a nice person, I posted my thesis on Arxiv:

http://arxiv.org/abs/1108.0452

I will be grateful to any person who could send me comments to improve the manuscript.

Comment: I think this should have been added as an edit to the original post, rather than as a separate answer

Comment: See also Theo Johnson-Freyd's comment above: "Please do not post a link to your thesis here."